# Iterate each column in CSV and apply encryption to each column

Tags: python, for-loop

Hello I am new to python and I tried to apply pycrypt.caesar.encrypt(column_name,column_number) function to each columns in CSV to encrypt. I tried something like this

```
import pycrypt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)
#col=df.columns
#print(col)
leng=range(len(df.columns))
print(leng)
j=0
for col in df.columns[0:,] and j in leng:
     #print(col)
     df['col']=df['col'].apply(lambda col: pycrypt.caesar.encrypt(col,j))
     print(df)
```

it throws with an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kalya/AppData/Local/Temp/Pseudo.py/main.py", line 12, in 
<module>
for col in df.columns[0:,] and j in leng:
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2419, 
 in __nonzero__
  raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

what am i doing wrong? i wanted to encrypt all columns in csv iteratively over a loop. please guide me

Comment: You should include the traceback or at least the exact line that raised the exception

Comment: Added traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the columns in the dataframe and apply a different ceasar shift to every column, you can do this:

```
for index,column in enumerate(df):
    df[column]=df[column].apply(lambda x: pycrypt.caesar.encrypt(x,index))

print(df)
```